# How to get the company name into the namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

My environment:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C#

I've read many articles and comments about, how I should organize my namespaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026

So my question is quite simple. How do I get the company and project name automatically in my namespace?

If I create subfolders in my project, so I get the following pattern:

```
<Project>.<Folder>.<Subfolder>.<..>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Solution1:**

  If you go to the `Properties` window of your `Project`, you can set the `Default namespace` (including the Company Name) and also the `Assembly name` in the `Application` tab. Below is a screenshot of this:

[image]

Now, after setting the default namespace, every time you add a new class to this project, it gets the above set namespace by default.

- **Solution2:**

Another solution is, every time you add a new project to your VS Solution, in the **`Add New Project`** template dialog, give the new project **`Name`** equal to **`CompanyName.ProjectName`**. This way your new project's `Default namespace` would include `Company Name` always (CompanyName.ProjectName) as shown in the Add New Project dialog screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your screenshots.

Comment: @Sam I added another solution (Solution2) to the answer just now, in case that would help you..

Answer (score 2):

VS will *by default* use your folder structure for namespaces.
But you can always simply edit the code to change your namespace(s).

And under **Project Properties, Application** you will find a setting for the **Default namespace**, which is used as the root for all other (folder-baed) namespaces. This is the place where you would normally enter your Company name.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add CompanyName as a name for the project as @Pravin Pawar said. If you ask me I won't add like that.

There is a option under **Project Properties** called **DefaultNamespace** (Application tab) where you can extend your namespace with company name.

My preference for most projects is to use *CompanyName.Project* as the default namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the default root namespace in the properties of the project - right click on the project file in Visual Studio, click on properties, then in the "Application" tab you can set the default namespace to include your company name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pravian's way for new solution. But for existed projects you should go to project properties in the `Application` tab to change `Default namespace:`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project, You specify the name of the project like `CompanyName.ProjectName` & then when you add new project to the same solution they follow the CompanyName.ProjectName namespace like

```
CompanyName.ProjectName.BAL
CompanyName.ProjectName.DAL
CompanyName.ProjectName.Client
```